# Issue with QTableView widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am having an issue with splitting the screen size between a `QTableView` widget and a `QWebEngine` widget which are both sharing a `QHorizontalLayout`.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the `QTableView` is taking up SO much space and giving almost nothing to the `QWebEngineView`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def init_pdf_view(self) -> None:
        self.pdf_view = WEB.QWebEngineView()
        self.pdf_view.setObjectName("pdf_view")    
        self.load_file("/path/to/pdf")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pdf_view)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(1, 1)

def init_table_view(self, sheet) -> None:
        if not self.table:
            self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.table.setObjectName("table")
            self.horizontalLayout_2.insertWidget(0, self.table)
        else:
            self.table.clear()
        self.load_input_sheet(sheet)

def load_input_sheet(self, file) -> None:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info=True)
        df = pd.read_excel(wb)
        self.input_sheet = df[df.columns[:3]]
        self.input_instructions = df[df.columns[3:]]
        self.input_sheet.columns = ["", *self.input_sheet.columns[1:]]
        self.input_sheet = self.input_sheet.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
        self.input_sheet.fillna('', inplace=True)

        self.prepare_table()
        self.populate_Table(wb)
```

I have tried moving the `self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(1, 1)` to the `init_table_view` method or even have it in both, but that just switches the sizing so that the `QWebEngine` takes up all the space instead of the `QTableView`.

Additionally, I would like to make it so that the first column of the table in the table view always shows no matter what and that the rest of the columns will either stretch to fit (up to half the size of the screen) or be horizontally scrollable if too many columns.

I appreciate any help and let me know if you need more information to adequately answer my problem.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the stretch at all? If memory serves, the horizontal layout will distribute the space evenly to all items in it (as long as they have an expanding size policy).

Comment: Furthermore, you can set a minimum width to your table. The layout manager will not allocate less than that. As for 'stretching the other columns', that might not be so easy. I know that the last column has an according property, but all others usually have their width and that's it. There are ways around that, of course, but it's not easy.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Removing the stretch does not do anything. How can I specify the minimum and maximum width to be one half the size of the horizontal layout?

Comment: Seeing how I'm from the C++ side of Qt, I'm afraid I cannot help with the syntax. In my code, I want two items to take up all the space the third item does not absolutely need.
This translates to two assignments: `verticalLayout->setStretch(1, 1);` and `verticalLayout->setStretch(2, 1);`. Item '0' gets pushed to the upper rim, items 1 and 2 get all the remaining space divided. So 'setting the stretch to only one' is the wrong thing to do. Which is the order the functions are called? (This determines the indices)

Comment: @RefugnicEternium ohh I was using the stretch method incorrectly. I thought the stretch behaved similarly to when setting the stretch inside of qt designer (setting the stretch for each positionally). I was saying `setStretch(1,1)` in an attempt to set both to 1, but now I realize that it is index 1 to stretch 1. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Let me sum that up in an answer really quick so we can formally close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `setStrecht` is incorrect. `setStretch` takes two parameters, the first one being the index, the second one being the 'weight' of the component identified by the index.

This means, that by calling `setStretch(1, 1)` you are giving the widget at position '1' (second in line) a weight of '1', with all others 'unstretched' widgets having a weight of '0'.

This tells the layout manager to prioritize the widget at position '1' when it comes to distributing the size.

Hence there are two different approaches to solve your problem:

- Don't use stretch at all (the layout manager will then give all widgets the same space)
- Apply stretch to both of your widgets. This will make the layout manager divide all available space between the chosen widgets and shrinking all other widgets to their minimum size.

In this context, it's a good idea to apply the stretch only after all items have been added to the layout, so the indices have actually been set. Please note that the indices refer to the order the items were added to the layout manager.

Assuming you want to stretch both widgets, your code would look something like this:

```
def init_pdf_view(self) -> None:
        self.pdf_view = WEB.QWebEngineView()
        self.pdf_view.setObjectName("pdf_view")    
        self.load_file("/path/to/pdf")

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pdf_view)

def init_table_view(self, sheet) -> None:
        if not self.table:
            self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.table.setObjectName("table")
            self.horizontalLayout_2.insertWidget(0, self.table)
        else:
            self.table.clear()
        self.load_input_sheet(sheet)

#Somewhere in your main
init_pdf_view(self)
init_table_view(self)

self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(0, 1)
self.horizontalLayout_2.setStretch(1, 1)
```